# Existe-t-il un terme argotique pour « avocat » ?

Tags: argot

En anglais britannique (uniquement) on parle de « brief » : c'est un exemple de synecdoque, car les clercs donnent aux  avocats un fascicule de papiers relatif aux aspects du cas : c'est le « brief », dérivatif à son tour du verbe « to brief », informer.

Dans les feuilletons policiers français, notamment *Engrenages*, une bonne source d'argot de toutes sortes pour les non-français, les jeunes gens présentés devant le juge d'instruction Roban semblent utiliser simplement « avocat ».

N'existe-t-il pas des termes argotiques ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cet article : « [Le « basochard » libéral fait le ménage](http://lepeuple.be/isppc-le-basochard-liberal-fait-le-menage/83653) » paru en 2017 dans *[Le Peuple](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Peuple_(journal_belge))*,  nous donne un aperçu de quelques termes argotiques qui ont plus ou moins survécu pour désigner les avocats.

> La perception qu’a le peuple de la noble profession d’avocat se traduit en argot par des dizaines d’appellations plus ou moins valorisantes :  bavard, baveux, blanchisseur, lessiveur, robin, enjuponné, avocaillon, débarbot, babillard, débarboteur, pingouin, plaidaillon, teinturier, basochard …

*Avocaillon*, *baveux* et *bavard* sont probablement ceux qu'on rencontre le plus souvent de nos jours.

- *[Avocaillon](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avocaillon)* est péjoratif, comme l'indique le suffixe [*aillon*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/-aillon)  et désigne donc un avocat qu'on considère mauvais.
- *Bavard* est transparent, c'est le terme qu'[Albertine Sarrazin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albertine_Sarrazin) emploie le plus souvent dans ses romans pour parler des avocats.
- Le *baveux* c'est un « bavard », mais encore plus péjoratif.

Les autres termes sont très peu, ou pas, employés de nos jours.

- On peut supposer que le terme de *pingouin* est employé par métonymie avec la couleur noire et blanche de l'oiseau du même nom.
- Le [*plaidaillon*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plaidailler) (ou *plaidailleur*), est un terme péjoratif, c'est l'avocat qui plaide sur de petites affaires.
- Le *babillard* est transparent, c'est celui qui babille ([TLF B.](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/babiller))
- *Blanchisseur* tire son origine d'un jeu de mot né lors du procès de l'empoisonneur [Edmond Couty de la Pommerais](https://www.lefigaro.fr/actualite/2007/07/21/01001-20070721ARTFIG90896-les_empoisonneurs.php) dont l'avocat s'appelait Lachaud et on disait qu'il serait acquitté parce que  Lachaud « blanchit » (La [chaux](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaux_(mati%C3%A8re)) blanchit). Voir [l'entrée](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k109806d/f59.image.texteImage)  dans le *Dictionnaire d'argot fin-de-siècle* de Charles Virmaître (1894).
- *Débarbot* ou *débarbotteur* vient de *débarboter*, qui signifie « tirer d'affaire » en parlant de l'avocat défenseur d'un accusé et qui obtient son acquittement ou une peine légère,  le *Dictionnaire du français non conventionnel* (J. Cellard et A. Rey) signale que le terme n'est plus utilisé après 1930.
- *Lessiveur* et *teinturier* sont peut-être partis de blanchisseur, mais on peut facilement comprendre que l'avocat « blanchit » ou « lave » son client.
- Le *parfumeur* c'est celui qui [couvre son client de fleurs](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/couvrir_de_fleurs) (et donc qui le parfume).  Voir [l'entrée](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k109806d/f229.item.r=parfumeur) dans le *Dictionnaire d'argot fin-de-siècle*.

À mon avis les autres termes cités couvrent un champ professionnel plus large que la profession d'avocat.

- La *basochard* désigne un homme de loi en général, pas exclusivement un avocat. Vient de [*basoche*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basoche).
- Un *robin* (celui qui porte la « robe ») est plutôt employé pour un magistrat en général.
- L'*enjuponné* c'est celui qui porte une longue robe (le terme de « [jupon](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/jupon) » a désigné une tunique d'homme à manches) et désigne aussi bien un juge qu'un avocat.

Comment: « Avocaillon » n'est pas un terme d'argot pour « avocat » : (TLFi)  « Fam. et péj. Avocat médiocre ».

Comment: @LPH J'ai écrit « désigne donc un avocat qu'on considère mauvais ». La différence entre  mauvais et médiocre est vraiment infime dans ce cas. Et tous ces termes sans exception sont « plus ou moins valorisants », tels baveux, bavard, menteur, etc... qui sont dans le « moins ».

Comment: Ces termes ont presque tous des connotations  négatives mais ce sont des connotations qui n'opèrent pas une discrimination parmi les avocats quant à leur valeur alors qu '« avocaillon  » n'est pas de cette sorte : il n'englobe pas tous les avocats. De plus ce n'est pas de l'argot : le suffixe « -aillon » ne vient pas de l'argot. Il en est de même pour « plaidaillon » (rare, péj., fam. Celui qui plaidaille, qui ne fait que de petites plaidoiries, sans envergure et sans talent.).

Comment: @LPH Définition du mot argot : usage langagier propre à un milieu fermé souvent illégal. Dans ce cas il s'agit de l'argot des prisonniers ou de ceux qui ont affaire à la justice. Un mot d'argot peu éventuellement être familier ou péjoratif, ou ne pas l'être.

Comment: L'argot français c'est le vocabulaire dans un dictionnaire d'argot ou ce qu'un dictionnaire courant (le TLFi, par exemple) liste comme étant de l'argot ; tout autre terme dans un dictionnaire qui n'a pas cette description est du vocabulaire d'un autre registre. L'argot est un registre https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registres_de_langue_en_fran%C3%A7ais , https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/registre_argotique.

Comment: @LPH Ma définition est celle du *Dictionnaire historique en langue française*. Ensuite les étiquettes que mettent les concepteurs des dictionnaires sur les mots est de leur ressort et c'est **subjectif**. Par ailleurs pour moi le TLF (reflet de la langue des années 50-60) et le wikipedia/wiktionaire sont des ouvrages collaboratifs sans autorité scientifique (tout comme Stack Exchange), mais c'est un autre débat.

Comment: Voir aussi le rare _avocasson_ dans la vedette [avocat](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avocat/0) au TLF.

Answer (score 1):

On trouve les mot d'argot « baveux » et « bavard » ; c'est « bavard » qui est utilisé le plus souvent

> https://www.le-tresor-de-la-langue.fr/definition/baveux
>
> Argot «Avocat» (Ch.-L. Carabelli, [Lang. de la pègre]). Synonyme plus fréq. bavard.

Il me semble cependant que les termes français ne correspondent pas à « brief » car ils seraient beaucoup plus vulgaires, « bavard » étant celui qui serait le plus proche. L'anglais britannique « brief » pour « sollicitor » ou « defence lawyer » est un terme qui n'est que familier.

Voilà une liste des termes d'argot pour « avocat »  qui devrait être assez complète (et dont je ne connais pas un seul terme ni ne veut en connaitre un seul). Les mots non marqués d'une astérisque proviennent d'une première référence ([réf.1](https://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060709024541AAbOwCf&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAADKsLCSO9LXzgzdEGb_4YD72qQsbvZYWHHLp1tPLGYPuTeYQE73_GVzPUq67oH-dzdMt4sSEISxqjBvspabvmPbdL3XGj0OzX0BeTh1r39ZuBxz6s0HiR41WkNQ2gfutGv3VDHSKeInN_q_vM06uf_Lba6GBVKUhkbQRzLIB3zOj&guccounter=1)) et ceux marqués d'une astérisque d'une seconde, complément dû à un utilisateur qui ne souhaite pas être mentionné,
([réf.2](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Synonyme/769)) ; certains termes dans cette seconde liste sont indubitablement des synonymes d'argot, bien qu'il y en ait de douteux, comme par exemple « avocat des causes perdues » qui signifie tout simplement « avocat qui défend des cas qui n'ont pas une chance d'être gagnés » et qui est un terme de la langue correcte (voir ce [lien](https://www.rtbf.be/info/monde/detail_l-avocat-jacques-verges-est-mort-jeudi?id=8068158)). Il y en a même qui ne sont pas des synonymes  mais qui catégorisent des *types particuliers d'avocat* : « avocaillon », « plaidaillon », « avocat des cause perdues », peut-être d'autres ; ces termes-là ont été exclus de la liste des synonymes argotiques ci-dessous.

À n'en pas douter ils sont tous trop vulgaires pour correspondre à « brief ».

babillard
basochard*
bavard
baveur*
baveux
blanchisseur
chicanier*
cravateur
crosse (la)
crosseur
cuisinier
curieux
débarbot
débarboteur
débarbotteur
débardot
écorneur
enjuponné*
gerbier
gueule*
habillé de noir
lessivant
lessiveur
médecin
menteur
parfumeur
parrain
parrain jaspineur*
pénal*
pilier*
pingouin
puisatier*
rat de prison
robe noire*
robin*
ténor du barreau*
sondeur
trompe*
vermine
Zervinois gourd

*Les termes suivants sont douteux et ne doivent pas être reconnus comme étant de l'argot sans une vérification (que je n'ai faite que très partiellement).*

marchand de paroles  (Par exemple, « *marchand de rêves* » et « *marchand de sommeil* » sont des
                                    termes de la langue standard.)
avocat de(s) causes perdues (terme de la langue standard)
avocat de Térence
avocat sans cause
avocat de Pilate
avocat de balle
avocat des mouches

Comment: "Cravateur", "cuisinier" ... "parfumeur" (!) ... fascinant. Très drôle.

Comment: @mikerodent  Ça ne fait aucun doute, l'argot a un côté très drôle, ce qui contribue à en faire de la langue que l'on ne peut pas prendre au sérieux, mais aussi --Je le crois personnellement-- un côté bombastique et pédant (« la clarinette baveuse» pour le membre viril, « le système baveux » pour le lavabo d'un café).